# how to convert nested loops to nested comprehensive list in python?

Tags: python

I have problem convert 3 level loop to comprehensive list

```
for a in X:
  for b in a:
     for c in b:
        do(c)
```

I want it in list just as quick-tool to verify code.
I understand pros and cons and know itertools.chain function.

solution for 2 level is:

```
[do(b)      for a in X        for b in a]
```

solution for 3 level is:

```
[do(c)      for b in itertools.chain.from_iterable(X)         for c in b]
```

how it will looks without using chain ? just list expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[c for a in X for b in a for c in b]
```

is the flattened version of `X`. The `for` clauses appear in the same order that they do in the nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

thank you:

```
[c      for a in X         for b in a       for c in b]
```

in general for any number of levels and better mnemonic method:

```
[z      for a in A         for b in a       for c in b    ...    for z in y]
```